# Twitter4j search by user bio

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Does twitter provides API to search against user's bio? particularry twitter4j library

**UPDATE#1**
search by user bio means a search by some keyword which contains in user description/bio (User.getDescription()), and result must contain only those users which description contains this keyword

Bio is a 160 characters text in user's profile
[image: twitter user bio/description]

Comment: I've updated my question, pls take a look again

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a [`User`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html), whose profile you can read with `User.getDescription()`?

You can get a `User` object with `TwitterImpl.lookupUsers()` passing in an array of Twitter account IDs.

Comment: Thanks for answer, what I am looking for is a possibility to search by keyword which is a part of user description (User.getDescription())